# Why does typescript not allow optional parameters before required parameters?

Tags: typescript, google-closure-compiler, flowtype

i am using typescript for my project and noticed while writing a definition file that [openui5](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html) occasionaly uses optional parameters before required parameters.  e.g.

    `//  Defines a Javascript module with its name, its dependencies and a module value or factory.
    define(sModuleName?, aDependencies?, vFactory, bExport?);`

[Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf), [Flow Type](http://flowtype.org/docs/functions.html) and the [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler) all require a parameter list in this form:

`ParameterList:
RequiredParameterList
OptionalParameterList
RestParameter
RequiredParameterList , OptionalParameterList
RequiredParameterList , RestParameter
OptionalParameterList , RestParameter
RequiredParameterList , OptionalParameterList , RestParameter`

However, could this construct not be seen as equivalent to three overloaded functions, i.e.

```
define(vFactory, bExport?);
define(aDependencies, vFactory, bExport?);
define(sModuleName, aDependencies, vFactory, bExport?);
```

Comment: the internal structure of the function might use the value of `aDependencies ` as `vFactory ` if there is only 2 parameter. Only 1 argument is required but in the real definition of the function,  `sModuleName ` that is the first argument might correspond to different thing depending on the number of argument used in the call of the function

Comment: see the source code here : https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/jquery.sap.global.js#LC2660

Comment: So you're right, these definitions are equivalent to the one described in the doc, so the first 2 arguments are not real optionals arguments.

Comment: so in this case it is syntactic sugar, right? Do you have a counter-example where this translation would not make sense?

Comment: btw: go ahead and write  an answer and i will accept it.

Comment: Yes, syntactic sugar to keep the arguments in an order that make sense (module name and/or dependency before the function `vFactory`) with a language that does not allow function overload

Comment: counter-example: parameters with the same type.

Comment: yes, but you can still check the value of these params and define if it's "a" or "b" depends on the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, could this construct not be seen as equivalent to three overloaded functions

It could. But *all language features start at -100*. And there are not enough use cases to certify the complication.

Comment: what do you mean by "all language features start at -100" ? didn't get it

Comment: Its a popular language design decision. Original reference : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/ 